# Can't get even a simple method to inline (?)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, inline

Logically, I always assumed that very short and simple methods would get inlined by the C# Compiler and thus won't show any overhead compared to simply typing the code in the methods by hand...

Until today - when I tried to benchmark various methods and manually inlined code. Turns out that (for me) even the most simple code will show a method call overhead compared to its manually inlined counterpart.
Actually, I could find no clues as to *any* method being inlined - So I ran a simple test.

System used:

- Intel C2D E7200 (Dual Core) 2.53GHz
- 4GB DDR2
- Windows 7 64bit
- .NET 4.0
- Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate

All tests were performed **without Debug** and using **Release Configuration (Optimize Code)**.

Here's the code I used to benchmark:

```
static void Main()
{
    const int iterations = 250000000; // 250 million iterations
    Thread.Sleep(1000); // sleep for one second
    var sw = new Stopwatch();

    int s = 0;
    sw.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        // incrementing s by 1 in various ways
    }
    sw.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("Time: {0}ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

**[1]** First, I've simply benchmarked a simple increment command:

```
// in Main
for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
{
    s = s + 1;
}
```

Results from 5 runs:

1. 867ms
2. 877ms
3. 868ms
4. 865ms
5. 870ms

---

**[2]** Switching to a method call:

```
static int Increment(int a)
{
    return a + 1;
}
```

...

```
// in Main
for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
{
    s = Increment(s);
}
```

Results from 5 runs:

1. 2161ms
2. 2159ms
3. 2194ms
4. 2177ms
5. 2163ms

Ouch! Obviously there's an overhead for the method.

I've tried to use reflection, and printed `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name` from within the `Increment` method; it was indeed printing `Increment` - meaning the method isn't inlined.

Next I've tried to add the `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]` attribute to the method - **but the benchmark time stayed exactly the same**.

In Debug mode and with Optimize Code set to false, the first test is slightly slower while the second one is about two times slower; and yet again the *NoInlining* attribute doesn't impact performance.

---

**Am I doing something wrong here that I fail to make even such a simple method work without an overhead? Why is this happening?**
Surely this can't be expected behavior - or is it?

*Note: Similar testing in Java shows no overhead to such a method call. (using Eclipse + JDK 1.7, Java also seems to be **A LOT** faster at this.)*

Comment: note that in .NET 4.5 you can actually force the compiler to try and inline your method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimploptions%28v=VS.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 10):

If you're running the program from within Visual Studio, make sure you use the *Start Without Debugging* command; otherwise, some optimizations like inlining may be disabled.

If I first use the *Start Without Debugging* command to run the program, *then* attach the debugger and look at the x86 disassembly of the `for` loop, I get the same thing whether the loop increments `s` directly or calls `Increment`; that is, the method call is inlined:

```
00000049  xor         eax,eax
0000004b  inc         ebx
0000004c  inc         eax
0000004d  cmp         eax,0EE6B280h
00000052  jl          0000004B
```

In contrast, if I use the *Start Debugging* command to run the program, then the method call is not inlined:

```
00000060  xor         edx,edx
00000062  mov         dword ptr [ebp-0Ch],edx
00000065  nop
00000066  jmp         0000007D
00000068  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-8]
0000006b  call        dword ptr ds:[00801F50h]
00000071  mov         dword ptr [ebp-10h],eax
00000074  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-10h]
00000077  mov         dword ptr [ebp-8],eax
0000007a  inc         dword ptr [ebp-0Ch]
0000007d  cmp         dword ptr [ebp-0Ch],0EE6B280h
00000084  jl          00000068
```

Comment: Indeed I am using the *Start Without Debugging* command (Ctrl + F5). It shows in that VS doesn't go into Debug View. Also, how can I view the x86 disassembly of a program compiled by the VM?

Comment: Here's what I did: I put a `Console.ReadLine()` call at the beginning of `Main`, set a breakpoint on the `for` loop, and used the *Start Without Debugging* command. Then I used the *Attach to Process* command to start debugging and pressed Enter in the console window. When the breakpoint was hit, I went to Debug > Windows > Disassembly.

Comment: To be honest that still doesn't help me. Fact is, there is an overhead which I can't get rid of - one which shouldn't be there in the first place.

Comment: What happens if you repeat the benchmark several times by wrapping it in a `for (int c = 10; c > 0; --c) { var sw = ... }` loop?

Comment: I've just tried that, and the same result (a few milliseconds±) just appears 10 times... :(

Comment: But calling the method is consistently slower than just incrementing the variable? When I try it, I get comparable times in either case.

Comment: For me that's obviously not the case, and I wish to find a fix and the reason as to why this is happening.

Comment: Are you sure optimizations are enabled in Release mode? Try opening the .exe in ILDASM or Reflector and look at the argument to the `DebuggableAttribute` constructor in the manifest. In my Release build, the value is `01 00 02 00 00 00 00 00` (ILDASM) and `IgnoreSymbolStoreSequencePoints` (Reflector). In my Debug build, the value is `01 00 07 01 00 00 00 00` (ILDASM) and `DisableOptimizations | EnableEditAndContinue | IgnoreSymbolStoreSequencePoints | Default` (Reflector).